# Negative & Positive Percentage Calculation

Tags: math

Let's say i have 3 sets of numbers and i want the % of their difference.

```
30 - 60
94 - 67
10 - 14
```

I want a function that calculate the percentage of the difference between each 2 numbers, and the most important is to support positive and negative percentages.

Example:

```
30 - 60 : +100%
94 - 67 : -36% ( just guessing )
10 - 14 : +40%
```

Thanks

Comment: The numbers you're providing don't really make any sense. Could you tell us what numbers we should actually be outputting instead of making up stuff that looks about right?

Comment: Getting there, but not right. 10 - 14 is a 40% increase, not 2%

Comment: @Eineki do not change question logic =) 30 + 0.5 * 60 = 60, 94 - 0.287 * 94 = 67, 10 + 0.285 * 14 = 14; This is strange logic but this is question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is pretty basic math.

% difference from x to y is `100*(y-x)/x`

Answer (score 6):

The important issue here is whether one of your numbers is a **known reference**, for example, a theoretical value.

With no reference number, use the **percent difference** as

```
100*(y-x)/((x+y)/2)
```

The important distinction here is dividing by the average, which symmetrizes the definition.

From your example though, it seems that you might want **percent error**, that is, you are thinking of your first number as the reference number and want to know how the other deviates from that.  Then the equation, where `x` is reference number, is:

```
100*(y-x)/x
```

See, e.g., [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_difference), for a small discussion on this.

Answer (score 4):

for `x - y` the percentage is `(y-x)/x*100`

Answer (score 4):

Simple math:

```
function differenceAsPercent($number1, $number2) {
    return number_format(($number2 - $number1) / $number1 * 100, 2);
}

    echo differenceAsPercent(30, 60); // 100
    echo differenceAsPercent(94, 67); // -28.72
    echo differenceAsPercent(10, 14); // 40
```

Answer (score -1):

If the percentage is needed for a voting system then Andrey Korolyov is the only who answered correctly.

Example

10 votes for 1 vote against = 90% 
10 votes for 5 votes against = 50% 
10 votes for 3 votes against = 70% 
100 votes for 1 vote against = 99% 
1000 votes for 1 vote against = 99.9%

1 votes for 10 vote against = -90% 
5 votes for 10 votes against = -50% 
3 votes for 10 votes against = -70% 
1 votes for 100 vote against = -99% 
1 votes for 1000 vote against = -99.9%

```
function perc(a,b){
console.log( (a > b) ? (a-b)/a*100 : (b - a)/b*-100);
```

}

Answer (score -2):

```
$c = ($a > $b) ? ($a-$b)/$a*-100 : ($b-$a)/$b*100;
```

In Ukraine children learn these math calculations at the age of 12 :)

Comment: I write enterprise level applications and i can't calculate that too. There are tons of reasons people could have missed that.